# Как обновить БД SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть БД. После создания появляется необходимость в добавлении таблиц но для этого надо вызвать метод onUpgrade и когда вызовается этот метод просто создается новая база с 0.И надо всё самому туда переписывать .Это очень нудно и пустая трат ресвремени.Как обойти эту проблему можно ли создать таблицу уже в готовой Бд без надобности звать onUpgrade

Comment: Покажите код метода `onUpgrade(...)`.

Comment: так тебе и надо звать onUpgrade и там описать миграцию на новую версию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы что то путаете. `onUpgrade()` вызывается самой системой при изменении версии БД (версия возвращается методом `SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()` и задается при создании БД).

Вручную `onUpgrade()` не вызывается.

Чтобы добавить в рантайме таблицу достаточно вызвать `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()` с DDL скриптом создания таблицы.

Хорошим тоном будет после создания таблицы инкрементировать версию БД...

Comment: спасибо Да точно !